# WPF Datagrid, display an X in a column based on value

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid that contains rows that are simply Description/Value couples

What I'd like instead of simply "Description" and "Value" columns would be columns from 1 to 4 (Range of possible values) and display an X in the column corresponding to the value

In other words, rather than

```
Description | Value 
--------------------
Desc1       |   2
Desc2       |   4
```

Something like

```
Description | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
----------------------------
Desc 1      |   | X |   |   
Desc 2      |   |   |   | X
```

I was thinking about doing that by doing that in the object but that's quite ugly and I imagine it would be possible in WPF

Edit :

Adding to the already thought-of answers was putting "X" in all the columns and using 4 converters that would toggle visibility, but I think this may be do-able with only 1 converter or maybe a totally another way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by customization Grid Template but easy and best way that i think is using a viewmodel like this:

```
  public class MyViewModel
{

    public MyViewModel(MyModel model)
    {
        Model = model;
    }

    public MyModel Model { get; set; }
    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return Model.Description;
        }
    }

    public string One
    {
        get
        {
            if (Model.Value == 1)
                return "X";
            else
                return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    public string Two
    {
        get
        {
            if (Model.Value == 2)
                return "X";
            else
                return string.Empty;
        }
    }
    public string Three
    {
        get
        {
            if (Model.Value == 3)
                return "X";
            else
                return string.Empty;
        }
    }
    public string Four
    {
        get
        {
            if (Model.Value == 4)
                return "X";
            else
                return string.Empty;
        }
    }

}
```

so you can just pass your model and bind a list of this ViewModel.

Comment: I think I can go with this one, this is the less "weird" since I only have 4 columns

Answer (score 1):

If you really are working with integers, you can put a `Canvas`, and one X inside it. Then bind the `Value` to `Left` of the X, and use a converter to transform the value so that 1 gets to 0, 2 gets to something like 20, etc. (I can suggest `(v - 1) * 20`)

And about the second idea you wrote in your question, you are not forced to use converters if these are inside some template. Use the `Triggers` of the template. Add some `DataTrigger`, bind it to the value, and set the `Value` of `DataTrigger` to 1, for example. Then put a `Setter` inside the `DataTrigger` to set the `Visibility` of the corresponding X. (This one has the draw back that you should put a `Name` on all of the X's.)